# Combining print statements with list comprehension in python

Tags: python, printing, list-comprehension, polling

I'm writing code to send and receive messages in python using a GSM modem.

Whenever a new message is received I get the following response in a list x after reading from a serial port object.

```
+CMTI: "SM",0 # Message notification with index
```

I'm polling for this indication and I've made use of list comprehensions to check whether I have received the above response

```
def poll(x):
    regex=re.compile("\+CMTI:.......")
    [m for l in x for m in [regex.search(l)] if m]
```

This seems to be working however I want to add a print statement whenever a match is found like

```
print "You have received a new message!"
```

How can I combine the print statement with the above?

Comment: Unless you want to hack a solution, use a normal loop.

Comment: You realise you arn't storing that list?

Comment: You don't put print statements in list comprehensions, it's bad python. Also as @Serdalis said you aren't storing the list

Comment: If by "working" you mean "it's not doing anything so it's not breaking" then yes it's working :(

Comment: @Volatility can I make use of the above regex in a normal loop?

Comment: @Serdalis I am storing the list, this is just part of my code, the rest of it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568281/polling-for-new-messages-received-by-a-gsm-modem-using-python

Comment: @jamylak what do you suggest I do instead? also, where are the matched items stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a normal `for` loop, it can be done like this:

```
def poll(x):
    regex = re.compile("\+CMTI:.......")
    lst = []
    for l in x:
        for m in [regex.search(l)]:
            if m:
                lst.append(m)
                print "You have received a new message!"
```

Note that this list isn't being stored anywhere (outside the function scope) - perhaps you want to `return` it.

---

As a side note, the hacky solution:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def poll(x):
    regex = re.compile("\+CMTI:.......")
    [(m, print("You have received a new message!"))[0] for l in x for m in [regex.search(l)] if m]
```

But this is *very unpythonic* - use the other version instead.

Comment: the second answer is messy and not recommended by why "unpythonic"?  I would have thought replacing the nested loop with a list comprehension, as messy as it is, is generally considered more pythonic.  Just curious and trying to learn.  Thanks.

Comment: @TMWP the list comprehension in itself is not what is unpythonic, it is the fact that, as [jamylak mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677429/combining-print-statements-with-list-comprehension-in-python/15677765?noredirect=1#comment22255322_15677429), the second answer is printing within a list comprehension. List comprehensions were meant to generate lists, not as a shorthand loop.